# Is the position of 都 in a sentence important？ (example inside)

Tags: grammar, mandarin

In this instance i'm  trying to communicate "every" or "each"

What do you usually do on weekends?

你週末通常都做什麼

Vs

你週末都通常做什麼

Is there a *meaningful* difference in the position in this sentence? or is it just plain grammatically incorrect?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, 你週末通常都做什麼 is more natural.

你週末都通常做什麼 sounds ok, but not as natural as the first one.

There's no difference in meaning. I don't think there's a strong reason as to why the first one sounds more natural. It might be all about conventions.

Note that some might take this differently based on their conventions.

By the way, 都 here is used to emphasize, not to convey *every* or *each*.

Comment: thank you! i see it is for emphasis, that makes perfect sense, as i thought that the 都 may not even be necessary in that sentence. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

People I ask don't like: 你周末都通常干什么？but they can't say why not.

What do you usually do on weekends? 
你周末通常都干什么？

You can leave 都 out:
你周末通常干什么？

What do you usually do each weekend? 
你每个周末通常做什么？

Comment: thanks. I thought that the 都 may just be unnecessary, but used for another reason here, comment above clarifed its for emphasis. thanks!